# Why does Installshield not delete the service when uninstalling on 2019 Datacenter, that is on a domain

Tags: server, dns, installshield

InstallShield 2020 R3.  I have a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter VM that is not on a domain, and another one that is on a domain.  I can install and uninstall, and the service is removed every time on all my test systems (2012 R2, 2016, 2019 Datacenter)...that are NOT on a domain.  On the 2019 Datacenter that is on a domain, when uninstalling, the service is stopped, but not deleted.  Why?  Something about security and permissions set on the domain controller?

Comment: Which service? Sounds like an InstallShield bug - contact their support group.

Comment: The installer puts down a service, and it is removed on every system except the domain system, when the product is uninstalled.  I don't have any reason at this time to suspect that the problem is with InstallShield.